# how to create a xml schema with java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, hyperjaxb

In order to create automatically an xml file to convert into jpa clases later I'm trying to create the estructure with the classes from de hyperjaxb3 package.
This is how I'm creating the objects:

```
Annotation an = new Annotation();
Appinfo ap= new Appinfo();
en.setName("Entidad");

ap.setContent(en);

an.setContents(ap);
schema1.setAnnotation(an);
```

Then in the console (or exporting to a xml file) it generate the next lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:extensionBindingPrefixes="hj orm" xmlns:hj="http://hyperjaxb3.jvnet.org/ejb/schemas/customizations" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:tns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" targetNamespace="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:annotation>

<xsd:appinfo>
    //The Entity object should be generated here, but it does not.
</xsd:appinfo>

</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:schema>
```

I need to generate an Entity XML element inside the xsd:appinfo elementm just like this

```
<xsd:appinfo>
    <hj:entity></hj:entity>
</xsd:appinfo>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the relationship to Maven ?

Comment: sorry. you're right.. although The result will be converted then in jpa clases using maven, it's not related anyway.